# hangman pictures not displaying?

Tags: java

ok, so I am making a hangman game in java but the only problem I have is that the program doesn't display the actual "hangman" correctly. Here's my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Hangman1 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random ran = new Random();
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("word.txt"));   
    String dictionary = file.nextLine();

    char array2[];

    String wordlist[] = {"accoutrements","acumen","anomalistic","auspicious","bellwether","callipygian","circumlocution"};
    int number = ran.nextInt(7);
    String in = null;
    in = wordlist[number];
    //System.out.println(number);
    String guess;
    int numofchances = 9,k=0,p=0,q=0;
    array2 = new char[numofchances+1];

    boolean array[],b=true;
    array = new boolean[in.length()];
    for (int u=0;u<in.length();u++)
    {
        array[u]=false;
    }

    while(numofchances >= 1 && b){
        numofchances--;
        System.out.println("Enter your guess: ");
        guess = input.nextLine();
        if (q==0)
        {
        System.out.println("-------------");
        System.out.println("|            ");
        System.out.println("|            ");
        System.out.println("|            ");
        System.out.println("|            ");
        System.out.println("|         ");
        System.out.println("|         ");
        System.out.println("|");
        System.out.println("-------------");
        }
        else if (q==1)
        {
            System.out.println("-------------");
            System.out.println("|        |   ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|");
            System.out.println("-------------");
        }
        else if(q==2)
        {
            System.out.println("-------------");
            System.out.println("|        |   ");
            System.out.println("|        o   ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|");
            System.out.println("-------------");
        }
        else if(q==3)
        {
            System.out.println("-------------");
            System.out.println("|        |   ");
            System.out.println("|        o   ");
            System.out.println("|       /    ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|");
            System.out.println("-------------");
        }
        else if(q==4)
        {
            System.out.println("-------------");
            System.out.println("|        |   ");
            System.out.println("|        o   ");
            System.out.println("|       /|   ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|");
            System.out.println("-------------");
        }
        else if(q==5)
        {
            System.out.println("-------------");
            System.out.println("|        |   ");
            System.out.println("|        o   ");
            System.out.println("|       /|\\ ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|");
            System.out.println("-------------");
        }
        else if(q==6)
        {
            System.out.println("-------------");
            System.out.println("|        |   ");
            System.out.println("|        o   ");
            System.out.println("|       /|\\ ");
            System.out.println("|        |   ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|");
            System.out.println("-------------");
        }
        else if(q==7)
        {
            System.out.println("-------------");
            System.out.println("|        |   ");
            System.out.println("|        o   ");
            System.out.println("|       /|\\ ");
            System.out.println("|        |   ");
            System.out.println("|       /    ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|");
            System.out.println("-------------");
        }
        else if(q==8)
        {
            System.out.println("-------------");
            System.out.println("|        |   ");
            System.out.println("|        o   ");
            System.out.println("|       /|\\ ");
            System.out.println("|        |   ");
            System.out.println("|       / \\ ");
            System.out.println("|            ");
            System.out.println("|");
            System.out.println("-------------");
        }
        char character = guess.charAt(0);
        array2[k] = character;
        k++;
        p = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<in.length();i++){
            char c = in.charAt(i);
            if(c == character || array[i]==true){
                System.out.print(c+" ");
                array[i] = true;
                p = 1;
            }else{
                System.out.print("_ ");
            }
        }
        if (p==0)
            q++;
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
            System.out.print(array2[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        b = false;
        System.out.println();
        for (int i=0;i<in.length();i++){
            if (array[i]==false)
                b=true;
        }
    }
    if(b){
        System.out.println("You lose.");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("You won.");
    }



}
}
```

The program always outputs the frame of "hangman" and it doesn't output the rest of the  pictures whenever a wrong letter is guessed.

Answer (score 0):

`JOptionPane` Takes a `String` as an argument to display to it. You can't use println() to print to it.

Instead of printing, you need to concatenate String with `\n`'s. Something like this.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       String hangman = 
           "-------------" + "\n" +
           "|        |   " + "\n" +
           "|        o   " + "\n" +
           "|       /|\\ " + "\n" +
           "|        |   " + "\n" +
           "|       / \\ " + "\n" +
           "|            " + "\n" +
           "|" + "\n" +
           "-------------";

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,hangman);
   }
}
```

Test this simple program out to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Note that for such a huge amount of string concatenation, StringBuilder is probably a good alternative.

Comment: @ajp15243 but the concatenation will be done by the compiler and if you used a `StringBuilder` it would be done at runtime

Comment: @vandale Ah, I think you're actually right, since these are all literal `String` objects without variables or loops or anything else complex, so in this specific case, `StringBuilder` would be bad. If this picture was created dynamically, where you have to determine if a particular part of the hangman guy is created or not (as per typical hangman rules), `StringBuilder` would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the hanged man that you are printing is based on the `q` variable so it should naturally be incremented every time the guessed letter can't be found in the word, but instead it is only incremented if no guessed letter has ever been found in the word. If you enter only wrong letters you will see the man appear piece by piece.

The problem is that incrementing `q` is controlled by `p==0`, and `p` is set to 1 if `c == character || array[i]==true`, where `array` is the record of all previous correctly guessed letters. You need to only set `p = 1` when `c == character`, not for anything else.

You may also want to consider using more descriptive variable names because that can help you spot these sorts of problems.